# How to find significant correlations in a large dataset

Tags: r, correlation

I'm using R.
My dataset has about 40 different Variables/Vektors and each has about 80 entries. I'm trying to find significant correlations, that means I want to pick one variable and let R calculate all the correlations of that variable to the other 39 variables.

I tried to do this by using a linear modell with one explaining variable that means: Y=a*X+b.
Then the lm() command gives me an estimator for a and p-value of that estimator for a. I would then go on and use one of the other variables I have for X and try again until I find a p-value thats really small.

I'm sure this is a common problem, is there some sort of package or function that can try all these possibilities (Brute force),show them and then maybe even sorts them by p-value?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Before you proceed with your analysis, read http://xkcd.com/882/

Comment: This is a nice vizualization tool: http://statpics.blogspot.cz/2013/11/correlation-ellipse-matrix.html

Comment: Don't you have some hypothesis based on theory? Why did you perform these measurements?

Comment: Part of the point of linear models is that you can predict your response variable based on several other variables at once, rather than having to run individual models for each predictor variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some sample data for reproducibility.

```
m <- 40
n <- 80
the_data <- as.data.frame(replicate(m, runif(n), simplify = FALSE))
colnames(the_data) <- c("y", paste0("x", seq_len(m - 1)))
```

You can calculate the correlation between two columns using `cor`.  This code loops over all columns except the first one (which contains our response), and calculates the correlation between that column and the first column.

```
correlations <- vapply(
  the_data[, -1],
  function(x)
  {
    cor(the_data[, 1], x)
  },
  numeric(1)
)
```

You can then find the column with the largest magnitude of correlation with `y` using:

```
correlations[which.max(abs(correlations))]
```

So knowing which variables are correlated which which other variables can be interesting, but please don't draw any big conclusions from this knowledge.  You need to have a proper think about what you are trying to understand, and which techniques you need to use.   The folks over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) can help.

Comment: The issue with this is that all variables are assumed to be numerical. What if the dependent variable i.e. "y" is a factor ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function `rcorr` from the package `Hmisc`.

Using the same demo data from Richie:

```
m <- 40
n <- 80
the_data <- as.data.frame(replicate(m, runif(n), simplify = FALSE))
colnames(the_data) <- c("y", paste0("x", seq_len(m - 1)))
```

Then:

```
library(Hmisc)
correlations <- rcorr(as.matrix(the_data))
```

To access the p-values:

```
correlations$P
```

To visualize you can use the package `corrgram`

```
library(corrgram)
corrgram(the_data)
```

Which will produce:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In order to print a **list of the significant correlations (p < 0.05)**, you can use the following.

1. Using the same demo data from @Richie:

   ```
   m <- 40
   n <- 80
   the_data <- as.data.frame(replicate(m, runif(n), simplify = FALSE))
   colnames(the_data) <- c("y", paste0("x", seq_len(m - 1)))
   ```
2. Install Hmisc

   ```
   install.packages("Hmisc")
   ```
3. Import library and find the correlations (@Carlos)

   ```
   library(Hmisc)
   correlations <- rcorr(as.matrix(the_data))
   ```
4. Loop over the values printing the significant correlations

   ```
   for (i in 1:m){
     for (j in 1:m){
       if ( !is.na(correlations$P[i,j])){
         if ( correlations$P[i,j] < 0.05 ) {
           print(paste(rownames(correlations$P)[i], "-" , colnames(correlations$P)[j], ": ", correlations$P[i,j]))
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

---

**Warning**

You should not use this for drawing any serious conclusion; only useful for some exploratory analysis and formulate hypothesis. If you run enough tests, you increase the probability of finding some significant p-values by random chance: https://www.xkcd.com/882/. There are statistical methods that are more suitable for this and that do do some adjustments to compensate for running multiple tests, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction.

Comment: It should be `correlations$P[i,j]  > 0.05` not `correlations$P[i,j]  < 0.05`

Comment: @SAVAFA, the code seems right `correlations$P[i,j] < 0.05`, I did a mistake above in the description, `(p < 0.05)` instead of `(p > 0.05)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to predict y using only one variable than you have to take the one that is mainly correlated with y. 
To do this just use the command `which.max(abs(cor(x,y)))`.  If you want to use more than one variable in your model then you have to consider something like the lasso estimator

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run a correlation matrix:

```
cor_result=cor(data)
write.csv(cor_result, file="cor_result.csv")
```

This correlates all the variables in the file against each other and outputs a matrix.